# Ubuntu Server ARM or Ubuntu Server Raspberry Pi?

Tags: server, raspberrypi

I am confused about which Version I should go for since the Raspberry Pi has an ARM Processor inside.
Sure "Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi" should be the right one since the Naming is really helpful, but is there any advantage of using the Ubuntu Server for ARM on Raspberry Pi? What are the differences at all?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ARM version seems to target ARM devices generally including SBCs and the Raspberry Pi version seems to target the Raspberry Pi series of small single-board computers specifically. Even if the two versions are identical except for the installation method, for the sake of posterity in my opinion you would have better luck with installing the Raspberry Pi version in case the two versions diverge from each other in the future. Also regarding the installation method, there are tutorials on the web about how to install the Ubuntu Raspberry Pi version specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any difference between Ubuntu Server ARM and Ubuntu Server Raspberry Pi, except for the installation method used.

Comment: Unless the difference in the Pi version is in the firmware, it needs special handling with it and the kernel installed to be able to boot. Only reason I can see for two specific versions like that to be listed using the same arch.